# OPENAM - amService-UrlAccessAgent Login multiple Times

Tags: security, identity, openam, opensso

In our deployement, We have 3 OpenAM instances behind a LoadBalancer, the stickiness is based on IP adresses, so that the Users always get on the same server.

My problem is that our max concurrent sessions is reached on each server after just one day of Workload.

When i analysed the amSSO audit log, i found out that my Web Agent (amService-UrlAccessAgent) opens sessions frequently (more than 20 sessions per minute) and those sessions never get destroyed (they all live loong :)).

Can you please help me to interpret this behavior?
didn't amService-UrlAccessAgent suppose to log once?

In advance Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that i got the solution. when i started to dig a little in the OpenAm code and in the agent code i have found out the folowing

```
           if ((isApplicationModule(authMethName) && 
                (ad.isSuperUser(userDN) || ad.**isSpecialUser**(userDN)))
                || isAgent(amIdentityUser))
           if (isAgent(amIdentityUser) && agentSessionIdleTime > 0) {
                ....
                session.setMaxSessionTime(Long.MAX_VALUE/60);
                session.setMaxIdleTime(agentSessionIdleTime);
                session.setMaxCachingTime(agentSessionIdleTime);
            } else {
                session.setExpire(false);
            }
```

and when You look just a little before, You found out that the value of *agentSessionIdleTime* is 0 if the property *com.iplanet.am.session.agentsessionidletim* isn't setup.

for the interpretation of the meaning of this property follow this link: [policy agent sessions to time out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19681-01/821-1818/gjwfg/index.html)

Thanks Peter For Your Help.
I will tell You soon if that works well on our production system.

Comment: but still, don't figure out why it didn't logout automatically

Comment: The solution i proposed is just a work around that works in our case, but indeed the problem still persiste. When you look the openam, at the first glance you can see that it hooks a cleanup methode to the process ending wich inconditionnaly logsout the agent. And it logs error if that process generates some, our logs are clean , no error no warnings on the agents log. After a small test on a test environement where i ve put the same configuration (same apache mod version, same agent conf file) i didn't reproduce the error, the agent logs out correctly

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of interesting things in your description:

- If you are using a web agent, then why are using it with amService-UrlAccessAgent? You should create a Web agent profile for your agent and use that account instead.
- It's not clear what web server are you using, so I'm assuming it's Apache. In that case make sure that you are NOT using prefork mode, the recommended mpm is worker, because it will require much less agent login in general. Nevertheless as far as I know the agent always logs itself out once the child process dies.
- You may also want to try to use a newer version of the webagent, or even a nightly if this problem keeps reoccurring.

Comment: Thanks a lot For Your answear, indeed We Use apache, and it's effectively in a prefork mode, this is because it hosts PHP apps and we do this trough mod_php (wich is incompatible with Worker mode).
concerning Your first question: we use the default profile because it feets our needs, i don't see specific tweaks that could be added trought a personlized profile (as the openAM newbie who i am).
i will try your last supposition as soon as i build a test environment... but i still keeping hope that i could invalidate those sessions trough configuration :)

Comment: You should create an agent profile under Access Control - realm - Agents - Web tab, and use the profile name/password when installing the web agent. At the moment it seems that you are using some really old version of the agent (I'm not even sure how it works without a proper Web Agent profile - because UrlAccessAgent isn't really one -, the agent should miss a lot of configuration options from the agent profile..).